# Library libuuid not loaded referenced from uuidgen image not found

Tags: macos, terminal, libraries, osx-elcapitan

I can not remember what did I do to get this error every command on my terminal. any advice?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libuuid.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/uuidgen
Reason: image not found
```

Is it safe to remove /usr/local/bin/uuidgen file? is it better to get the libuuid? how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

I just move /usr/local/bin/uuidgen to my desktop, hope I don't need it.